# Takes Two Clicks to Select New Feature

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I'm writing a web app using ESRI's Javascript API and a map I created in ArcMap 10.1 hosted on ArcGIS online (Feature Service, not WebMap).

I have written the code necessary to print attributes in a stationary DIV instead of creating a popup. The only problem is, I now have to click twice every time I want to select a new feature.

So, I select a feature, the DIV updates with the new attributes. I click on a different feature, nothing happens. I click on the same feature again and the attributes update in the DIV.

What is going on here? I'm using map.infoWindow.on() to listen for "selection-change". My code is below and the website is live [here](http://matthewiannowlin.com/planning/thesis/test.html).

```
popup = new Popup({popupWindow:false},domConstruct.create("div"));

map = new Map("Div1", { 
 basemap: "gray",
 center: [-86.14, 39.79],
 zoom: 11,
 infoWindow: popup,
});

featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://services1.arcgis.com/ROSiDsWkQXhsUAs0/arcgis/rest/services/Thesis.gdb-2015-01-19_(1)/FeatureServer/0",{
 mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
 infoTemplate: popupTemplate,
 outFields: ["*"]
});

map.addLayer(featureLayer);

popup.on("selection-change", function(){
 var feature = popup.getSelectedFeature();
 var content_MED_dolla = feature.attributes["MED_dolla"];
 document.getElementById("popupDiv").innerHTML = "<p>Median mortgage value: $" + content_MED_dolla + ",000</p>";

});
```

Comment: Just curious, why does the "selection-change" event throw the error? I'm dealing with this situation as well but need to capture the navigation events in the Popup for multi-selected features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
popup.on("selection-change", function(){
```

to

```
popup.on("set-features", function(){
```